# Mega menu (CSS only) hover not working correctly

Tags: html, css, megamenu

I'm trying to develop a mega menu for my Wordpress theme, but unfortunately I can't manage to make it look as wanted. See code and output here:

```css
#main-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}

div#main-navigation ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  width: 100%;}

#main-navigation ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;}

#main-navigation ul li ul {
    display: none;
    width:100%;}

#main-navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;}
    
#main-navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #e2001a;}

#main-navigation ul:hover li ul li ul li {
    display: inherit;
}
#main-navigation ul li:hover {
    width: auto;}
    
#main-navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;}
    
 
#main-navigation ul li:hover ul li {
    float: left;
    position: static;
    display: block;
    padding-top:0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
    
#main-navigation ul li:hover ul li ul {
    display: inherit;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
    
    
#main-navigation ul li:hover ul li ul li {
    float: none;
    padding-top: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
    
ul > li.mega-menu > a:after {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  content: '';
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

ul > li.mega-menu:hover > a:after {
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul id="menu-main-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="mega-menu"><a href="">Top Level Item</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="">Second Level Item 1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="">Third Level Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Third Level Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Third Level Item 3</a></li>
                        <!-- more li elements -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Second Level Item 2</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="">Third Level Item 5</a></li>
                        <!-- more li elements -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Another Top Level Item</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Second Level Item 4</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="">Third Level Item 12</a></li>
                        <!-- more li elements -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want the second Level to start always on the left and not adapt the width of the first Level when hovering, ie. the first level should always keep its original width (as of when not hovering).

Could someone please help out?

Comment: I see one problem, but I'm not sure if this is about your question. When you hover over the second menu item, the third menu item breaks down and is moved under the second menu item. Do you mean this problem?

Comment: You have that issue because your L2 is still in the flow. Try changing to position absolute for example :-)

Comment: @Laurent S. unfortunately, that doesn't change it. Only makes all level2s be below each other

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov that's only because the snippet window is too small. I want it to look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/epehcvhv/4/ but can't use this code because I can't have a div in it.